# Java android keep fragment running in the background

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I use this code for change fragment;

```java
 smoothBottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(i -> {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new homeFragment();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new searchFragment();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        fragment = new userFragment();
                        break;
                }
                return loadFragment(fragment);
            });
```

everything is okay but when I want to change fragment and go back to home fragment, I have a performance problem.

I think this code creates performance problem because blogmodel’s element count is at least 50

```java
blogAdapter = new blogAdapter(requireContext(), requireActivity().getWindow(), blogModels);
recyclerView.setAdapter(blogAdapter);
```

When I change the fragment, home fragment clears so when I go back, Home fragment reloads again.

Can I block this? I mean; How can i keep home fragment running? I'm using diffUtil.

Pls use basic english.